# UWP MediaElement - Preview Thumbnails on Hover Over the custom Slider

Tags: c#, uwp, slider, mediaelement, video-thumbnails

I'm using a media element to play video and a custom slider to seek that video. Can I able to preview the thumbnails of video when I over the mouse on slider (as like in the you tube videos) ?

```
   <MediaElement Name="videoMediaElement" AreTransportControlsEnabled="False"  Stretch="Fill" MediaOpened="videoMediaElement_MediaOpened"      MediaEnded="videoMediaElement_MediaEnded" 
    MediaFailed="videoMediaElement_MediaFailed" PointerPressed="videoMediaElement_PointerPressed"   CurrentStateChanged="Media_State_ChangedAsync" >
   </MediaElement>
   <Slider Name="timelineSlider" IsThumbToolTipEnabled="True" ThumbToolTipValueConverter="{StaticResource TooltipValueConverter}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="5,0,0,6" FontSize="12" Width="700" Height="50"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a preview of a media file using `Windows.Media.Editing.MediaComposition` class.

When you first load the media file, create a `MediaComposition` instance:

```
mediaComposition = new MediaComposition();
var mediaClip = await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync( videoFile );
mediaComposition.Clips.Add(mediaClip);
```

It is good to store the `MediaComposition` instance as a field so that it can be reused.

Now once you want to display the preview you can use the following method:

```
private async Task<BitmapImage> CreatePreviewAsync( TimeSpan atTime, int width, int height )
{        
    var thumbnail = await mediaComposition.GetThumbnailAsync(atTime, width, height, 
                           VideoFramePrecision.NearestKeyFrame);
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.SetSource(thumbnail);
    PreviewImage.Source = bitmapImage;
}
```

For more granularity you could use `VideoFramePrecision.NearestFrame`, but takes more time to process.

Comment: which event should I use to get the Timespan atTime of slider when I sliding on it? And How can I dynamically position the image ( PreviewImage)to the place where I sliding the slider?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I think the `ValueChanged` event is the best place to generate the preview. Also, the position could be calculated from the `Thumb` control of the slider - which you could get using `VisualTreeExtensions` in the UWP Community Toolkit

Comment: @MartinZikmund I think wht he is looking for is to get the seek preview when the user mouse hovers the sliders anywhere so the thumbnail should popup where the mouse pointer is and on the position of the video, also where the pointer is.